# SQL Server: Return Null if the first character is a number

Tags: sql-server

I have the following field called Field1:

```
132 16
Z23 12
231 11
JKK 11
```

I want to create a new column, Field2, so that if this column starts with a number, it'll return NULL, and if it starts with a letter, it'll return the whole string.

The example above would look like:

```
132 16     NULL
Z23 12     Z23 12
231 11     NULL
JKK 11     JKK 11
```

I'm thinking of doing it with

```
Field2 = CASE
  WHEN (first letter is a number) THEN NULL
  ELSE Field1
END
```

and I need help filling in the parenthesis.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Field2 = CASE
  WHEN Field1 like '[0-9]%' THEN NULL
  ELSE Field1
END
```

Comment: delete ^ from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use The next criteria:

```
col1 like '[0-9]%'
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create table #temp 
(col1 varchar(10))

insert into #temp values 
            ('132 16'),
            ('Z23 12'),
            ('231 11'),
            ('JKK 11')


select col1 , col2 = CASE
              WHEN col1 like '[0-9]%' THEN NULL
              ELSE col1
            END
from #temp

drop  table #temp
```

**Result:-**

[image]